# ExpressJS throwing multiple header error while I seem to be sending only one header

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I've got the following block of code:

```
router.put("/:_id", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

try {
    // Create the updated artist variable
    const artist: IArtist = req.body;

    const updatedArtist = await Artist.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params._id}, artist);

    return res.sendStatus(200).json(updatedArtist);
} catch (err) {
    // console.log(err);
    return res.sendStatus(400).send("Couldn't update artist");
}
```

});

This throws the following error:

```
(node:32408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:561:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\thimo\Documents\GitHub\FlexTix\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)  
    at ServerResponse.contentType (C:\Users\thimo\Documents\GitHub\FlexTix\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:599:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (C:\Users\thimo\Documents\GitHub\FlexTix\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:357:8)
    at C:\Users\thimo\Documents\GitHub\FlexTix\server\src\routes\artists.ts:44:20
    at step (C:\Users\thimo\Documents\GitHub\FlexTix\server\src\routes\artists.ts:33:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\thimo\Documents\GitHub\FlexTix\server\src\routes\artists.ts:14:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\thimo\Documents\GitHub\FlexTix\server\src\routes\artists.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

As far as I know, I'm only sending one header. How could I fix this problem?

Comment: The function itself works by the way, it updates the Artist in the Mongo database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.status()` instead of `.sendStatus()`. When you use `.json()` or `.send()` on top of `.sendStatus()` - express tries to set additional headers on top of response that is already sent due to `.sendStatus()`